# problem dragging the admons sdk.jar file into the eclipse libs folder

Tags: android, eclipse, file

When I try to do this it wont let me.  Any ideas? it starts to drag out of my downloads folder, but when i hit eclipse with the file it gives me that "no smoking" signal (circle with diagonal line through it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explorer or Finder to copy the file and paste in the project.  You can not drop into the tree over Eclipse.  You will need to know the path to the workspace folder and project folder.  After pasting the jar into the appropriate folder refresh the project in Eclipse.  Then you can set the library in project properties.

Comment: although a simple copy and paste did work..just pasted it into folder right in eclipse

Comment: Glad to see the problem was fixed.  Enjoy android.